# Google Cloud Memorystore connect from "App Engine Java Standard Environment"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

Is any tutorial how to properly do it from "App Engine Java Standard Environment"?

So documentation said that "You can't connect to a Cloud Memorystore for Redis instance from App Engine standard environment applications."
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex

But maybe there is plan to do it in future as same as it has done for python https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/redis/index.html?

Answer (score 2):

We are working on enabling this. We expect this to be available early Q2. One thing to note is that this will only be available for App engine second generation runtimes.

Product Manager
Cloud Memorystore